# How to change/add a tracker to a .torrent file using the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, transmission

I use transmission-daemon on Debian for my torrents.

For now, I've been using the website http://torrenteditor.com/ to add trackers to .torrent files.

I'd like to edit .torrent files directly using Linux command line, and change the associated tracker easily (or add one, if possible).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can edit the torrent files themselves using [transmission-edit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-edit). Supposedly `transmission-edit -a udp://tracker my.torrent` should work.

If you have already added the torrent file to transmission, you can use [transmission-remote](https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-remote) to update it, e.g. `transmission-remote -n 'user:pass' --torrent 10 --tracker-add 'udp://tracker.url:1337/announce'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to think it was impossible. Can I ask why it is "transmission-remote" and not "transmission-cli" or "transmission-daemon", though?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  You said that you are running the daemon already. In order to interact with that already running daemon, you are supposed to use `transmission-remote`.  `transmission-cli` is a full blown torrent program itself, i.e. the daemon with a frontend. One frontend for the `transmission-daemon` is the `transmission-remote` program.

Comment: Can one do this with text editor?